# ASP.NET DropDownList generated by repeater not firing OnSelectedIndexChanged after being created

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, event-handling, repeater, asprepeater

Bit of a tough bug I'm dealing with. I've created an ASP DropDownList using a Repeater like so in my .aspx file:

#### mypage.aspx

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptTemplateFields" runat="server"
                      DataSource='<%# rptrDataSource %>' 
                      OnItemDataBound="rptTemplateFields_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepeater" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                      AutoPostBack="True" 
                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepeater_SelectedIndexChanged"
                      width="360" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
        </asp:DropDownList>                     
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And I'm populating these dropdowns with the following in my codebehind:

#### mypage.aspx.cs

```
protected void rptTemplateFields_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        dynamic field = e.Item.DataItem;
        BugFieldName fieldName = field?.FieldName;
        string fieldContent = field?.FieldContent;

        var allowedValues = GenerateAllowedValues(fieldName);

        if (!fieldName.IsNullOrUnsetValue() && !allowedValues.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            var ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlRepeater") as DropDownList;
            ddl.ID = "_ddlField" + fieldName;
            ddl.Attributes.Add("Name", "_ddlField" + fieldName);

            ddl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                

                    ddl.DataSource = allowedValues;
            ddl.SelectedValue = allowedValues.Contains(fieldContent)
                ? fieldContent
                : null;
            ddl.Visible = true;
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void ddlRepeater_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddlRepeater = sender as DropDownList;
    var state = (string)ViewState[ddlRepeater.Attributes["Name"]];

    if (state != ddlRepeater.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        ViewState[ddlRepeater.Attributes["Name"]] = ddlRepeater.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

The problem is the first time I click the drop down list and change the item (immediately post creation and databind), a page load is triggered and the ddl.SelectedValue, etc. state is wiped and the DropDownList's "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event handler does not fire.

Immediately following this page load, subsequent changes in the DropDownList DO trigger OnSelectedIndexChanged and the list's state is preserved. I imagine something funky is going on with the postback and data binding, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

So far I've tried using other event handlers without any luck. I've confirmed that a page load does occur and it is a PostBack. I added `<%@ Page ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>` to my aspx file. I also tried using an `ItemCommand` listener on the repeater. This also did not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this issue looks to be that you set the data source of the repeater in the markup. So, with any post-back, your re-load and re-binding code runs again, and that results in the loss of any selecting you make (re-binding reruns your row data bound code again and again). So, any changes you make are lost due to the post back and the reloading of data again.

The simple solution is to bind the data to the repeater in code behind, and ONLY one time.

Hence, say this simple markup:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"
        OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h4>Booking Infomration</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPerson" runat="server" Width="200px"
                Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>'>
            </asp:Label>

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hotel:"
                Style="margin-left: 30px">
            </asp:Label>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel" runat="server"
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="HotelName"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboHotel_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <hr style="height: 2px; border: none; background-color: black" />

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

<div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
    <h3>Combo box selected row information</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInfo" runat="server"
        TextMode="MultiLine" Height="160px" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

And our code behind, and note VERY close how we ensure only a binding of the data on the first page load (IsPostBack = false).

Hence this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels
            ORDER BY HotelName";

        rstHotels = General.MyRst(strSQL);

        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY FirstName";
        Repeater1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList cboHotel = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("cboHotel");
            cboHotel.DataSource = rstHotels;
            cboHotel.DataBind();
            cboHotel.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", "0"));

            DataRowView rowData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;  // current binding row data
            if (rowData["Hotel_id"] != DBNull.Value)
                cboHotel.SelectedValue = rowData["Hotel_id"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void cboHotel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cboHotel = (DropDownList)sender;
        RepeaterItem rptRow = (RepeaterItem)cboHotel.NamingContainer;

        string sInfo = "";
        sInfo += $"Row index selected = {rptRow.ItemIndex}\n";

        Label lblPerson = (Label)rptRow.FindControl("lblPerson");
        sInfo += $"Row person information = {lblPerson.Text}\n";
        sInfo += $"combo Hotel id = {cboHotel.SelectedItem.Value}\n";
        sInfo += $"combo Hotel Name (text) = {cboHotel.SelectedItem.Text}\n";

        txtInfo.Text = sInfo;   
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, often it can be ok to place some data source in the markup, but the instant you have post backs and additional code logic, then I suggest you "take control" of the data binding by using code behind, and not leave up when re-binding may, or may not reoccur.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm starting to see the problem. Unfortunately the items rendered by the drop down are dependent on which repeater is loaded (different fields with different allowed values) which makes up front data load impossible. Any ideas how to address that scenario?

Comment: But note how each row, I do in fact set the combo box to the given data row. In other words, I load the combo box (with a data source), and THEN I set the value of the combo box to the given row data used for binding. So, my example DOES set the combo box based on the one data row for that given repeater row. Was there addtonal work or processing you required for the one data row and binding? Your posted code does seem to try and set the combo box for the one given row, but so does my sample code. So, sample code loads the combo choices, and THEN sets the combo box to the current row value

Comment: So, it not clear what you mean by up-front load? We can dynamic load each combo box on the given row to anything we want. Once loaded, you could even say have 2 combo boxes in which the 2nd combo cascades and gets set based on the value in the first combo box. So, nothing suggests, hints or implies we can't load up each repeater row anyway we want. I mean, I set the DataValue column, and the DataText column in the markup, but nothing stops me from setting the 2 columns in the row data bind code that setups up the combo box. (or having a 100% different data source for each combo box on a row)

Comment: Ahh, I think I'm seeing our disconnect. Interestingly in the case I'm having trouble with, the request IS coming through as a postback, therefore missing our data load entirely.

Comment: For clarity, the postback is fired on dropbox changed, but the OnSelectedIndexChanged event not does only a single time. 

IE the controls are loaded and populated, the first time I manipulate a drop down the postback triggers but the event does not. The second time I manipulate that dropdown the even fires as expected.

Comment: I see the cbo starts with visible = false. That means the control and markup is NEVER sent to the browser side (which means no JavaScript can mess with the control). However, as my posted example shows, the combo box OnSelectedINdexChanged fires just fine, so we are missing some additional details, since as my posted code shows, the selected index not only fires, but you can see the code ALSO can with great ease pick up the current row, and update the floated text box to the right. As I stated, you have to be careful, since a GV data bind will re-trigger the row data bound event.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the combo selected index change event, since the repeater one does not matter. So, there must be some addtitional code or somthing going on here. As I stated, you really do NOT want to re-trigger a re-bind of the GV, and doing so in most cases will cause loss of user's selection. But, either way, my combo does fire. I would consider using style="display"none" in palce of visible = false, since as noted, controls having visible = false means they are not ever sent nor rendering in the browsers markup. but, we are missing some detail here.

Comment: What all of above suggest is your data binding is NOT placed in the first !IsPostBack event. you cannot write nor build a working page if you don't use that if (!IspostBack) block to setup your controls. Remember, on EVERY post back, the page load event will fire first and if you "re-run" the databinding code again, then you lose control settings, and most likley the selected index event can't run, since you re-bouded the gv, and thus re-bounded the combo box again. My last 200+ web pages all have that !IsPostBAck stub, and without as such, you can't build a working page.

Comment: Albert, thank you! It appears it was an issue with the `ddl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;` code and `visible=false`. All working as expected now.